# Get views to filter by {search_dataset} instead of {search_index}

Tags: views, search

I am working on a retrofit to an old site where I need to rework a View.

I need to add a simple exposed filter for the standard search data (Search API is not an option).

So, my View looks like

[image]

and the query looks like

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, SUM(search_index.score * search_total.count) AS score
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {search_index} search_index ON node.nid = search_index.sid
LEFT JOIN {search_total} search_total ON search_index.word = search_total.word
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND( (search_index.type = 'node') AND( (search_index.word = 'test') ))))
GROUP BY search_index.sid, score, node_title, nid
HAVING (( (COUNT(*) >= '1') ))
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This is doing the query against `{search_index}`, but I need to filter against `{search_dataset}` with a `WHERE search_dataset.data LIKE '%test%'`

views/modules/search.views.inc has `{search_dataset}` as a table in `search_views_data()`.

`views_handler_filter_search` and `views_handler_argument_search`have the logic to add this table, based on `!$this->search_query->simple()`.

How do you enable this in the UI?  I can query alter this to get what I want, but I would really like to find this setting or at least try to backtrace how the query is decided to be "not simple".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Views is much smarter than I am.

That setting is not exposed to the UI. `{search_dataset}` is only added if it is needed.

If the filter input is a single word, or multiple words separated by spaces or commas, the handler will turn this into a OR clause against `{search_index}`:

[image]

If you are familiar with the Search module, you will know that all words that have been indexed are in `{search_index}`.  In other words, a single word query doesn't need to be run against `{search_dataset}`.

If you search for multiple words in double quotes, `{search_dataset}` is magically added in and the query turns into a `LIKE`:

[image]