# Search filter result score

Tags: views

I'm seeing an interesting anomaly (?) I'm trying to get to the bottom of. I've set up a view with an exposed filter Search: Search Terms. I am trying to mimic the result set offered by standard drupal search module, but am finding interesting results based on the score.

When I search for "term1" (no quotes) in both standard site search, and within the view:

- result set is similar, but not the same.
- actual score returned for items in sitewide search, and views search are different.

So I guess, my question really is "where is the search modules' results score coming from, and how can I recreate it within a view?"

I should add I am not using any special search modules at all, just core search module.

**Core search sql, as viewed from devel:**

```
SELECT i.type AS type, i.sid AS sid, SUM((45.0578814438 * i.score * t.count)) AS calculated_score 
FROM search_index i 
INNER JOIN node n ON n.nid = i.sid 
INNER JOIN search_total t ON i.word = t.word 
INNER JOIN search_dataset d ON i.sid = d.sid AND i.type = d.type 
WHERE (n.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND( (i.word = :db_condition_placeholder_1) )AND (i.type = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND( (d.data LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_3 ESCAPE '\\') ) GROUP BY i.type, i.sid 
HAVING (COUNT(*) >= :matches) 
ORDER BY calculated_score DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

**From the created view:**

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type, SUM(search_index.score * search_total.count) AS score, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 'search_test:page' AS view_name
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {search_index} search_index ON node.nid = search_index.sid
LEFT JOIN {search_total} search_total ON search_index.word = search_total.word
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND( (search_index.type = 'node') AND( (search_index.word = 'test') ))))
GROUP BY search_index.sid, score, node_title, nid, node_type, field_data_body_node_entity_type, view_name
HAVING (( (COUNT(*) >= '1') ))
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things affecting the difference in results. I'm sure you noticed the queries differ slightly.

- The first and core issue is that the `search` module's main table is `search_index`, so each row is built around entries in that table and then joined outward to get more information. Your `view` is built around the `node` table and joined the other direction to search index.
- The core search uses inner joins to get node data, which will be more limiting in its result sets (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).)
- The `search_dataset` table isn't joined from the Views search (see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115108/get-views-to-filter-by-search-dataset-instead-of-search-index) for an explanation of why.)
- Core search multiplies the search scores by relevance, which shouldn't affect their ranking, but looks confusing. See line 496-500 of `search.extender.inc`.

I know I only answered the first half of your question, but I hope this helps. I'm not sure it's possible to get a View to exactly mirror your search results without considerable customization.